# ioctl return "inappropriate ioctl for device" with VIDIOC_S_CROP, attempting open camera in qt creator

Tags: qt, ubuntu, video, v4l2

Environment: laptop, Ubuntu, qt creator

I wanna open the camera of the laptop and display the video in label in qt creator.

When I run the program, nothing in the label.

the part of code occur the error

```
if(-1 == ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_CROP, &crop))
    {
        if(EINVAL == errno)
        {
            emit display_error(tr("VIDIOC_S_CROP not supported"));
        }
        else
        {
            emit display_error(tr("VIDIOC_S_CROP: %1").arg(QString(strerror(errno))));
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

error occur in else.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1) What is `fd`? 2) What is `crop`?

Comment: @duskwuff fd is the value returned by open("/dev/video0", O_RDONLY), VIDIOC_S_CROP defined in v4l2 about controlling camera